# Current Year Sales and Previous Year Sales in the same table?

Tags: datetime, teradata

Good Morning,

I am looking to add 'Previous Year Sales' to the same week into a Teradata pull, but I am failing on the coding. The Baseline I would code to get the sales of that week/year would be:

```
SELECT a."WEEK_NBR" AS "YearWeek"
, SUM(a."Sales") AS "CurrentYearSales"

FROM "SALESTABLE" AS a
```

Which would result in:

```
YearWeek  CurrentYearSales

201901    $7,499

201902    $2,300

201903    $6,360


...

202001    $4,500

202002    $9,000

202003    $8,500
```

I want to be able to have the Prior year's sales same week on the same line, if the prior year is there in the data table. That way the finished table would look like:

```
YearWeek  CurrentYearSales PriorYearSales

201901    $7,499           NULL

201902    $2,300           NULL

201903    $6,360           NULL
...

202001    $4,500           $7,499

202002    $9,000           $2,300

202003    $8,500           $6,360
```

When I search, all I can find is how to do this with the current week's data, but is this possible with all records in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As you SUMmed the data you need to aggregate *before* the join.

You need a self join, assuming `WEEK_NBR` is numeric:

```
with cte as 
 (
   SELECT a."WEEK_NBR" AS "YearWeek"
    , SUM(a."Sales") AS "CurrentYearSales"
   FROM "SALESTABLE" AS a
   group by 1
 )
select ...
from cte as t1
left join cte as t2
on t2.YearWeek = t1.Ye arWeek- 100
```

As @Andrew noted, this will also work for a string because Teradata will do an automatic typecast to a float when you add a number to a string or compare numeric and string (I would prefer writing an explicit type cast though)

Comment: For better or worse, Teradata will do an implicit cast here if week_nbr is char or varchar.

Comment: Sorry, what would go where the elipsis is? (also edited the query replacing a with t1?)

with cte as 
 (
   SELECT t1."WEEK_NBR" AS "YearWeek"
    , SUM(t1."Sales") AS "CurrentYearSales"
   FROM "SALESTABLE"
   group by 1
 )
select SUM(t2."Sales") AS "PriorYearSales"
from cte as t1
left join cte as t2
on t2.WEEK_NBR = t1.WEEK_NBR - 100

Comment: The select would be something like `select t1.week_nbr as yearweek, t1.CurrentYearSales as CurrentYearSales, t2.CurrentYearSales as PrevYearSales from...`.

Comment: I am getting`Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5628 : HY000] Column WEEK_NBR not found in t2 or t1. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.568 
 
STATEMENT 1: WITH  failed.`

Comment: You renamed it in the CTE. Use t1.YearWeek instead of t1.Week_Nbr.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks for catching it, fixed :-)

Comment: The results coming out are a bit wacky. Everything is fine for 2019 as the current year and the null for prior year match up. When the data is for 2020, things get skewed. I was expecting ~$45k in sales for week 1, 2020 but the value came back at ~$2.3M. I am not sure how things are totaling using this code for the 2020 year.

Comment: Check the result of the cte-Select, if it's correct, you got something else wrong. Did you use the Select from Andrew's comment?

Comment: Yes, the cte SELECT is correct. It was in the secondary piece. All works now!